# Sql UPDATE once then Die

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like an sql query that UPDATES once and then dies.

The update is applicable to one row (where user ID = x)

I would like to change one of the users OFF to ON (just one)

so the database is

```
user | monday | tuesday | wednesday | thurs | fri | sat | xmas | easter | etc
1    | off     | hols   |   on      | off   | on  |  x  |  on   | sick  | etc

mysql_query("UPDATE shifts SET ??  WHERE userID  = '".$_SESSION['userID']."' ")or die("Query failed:".mysql_error());
```

So the column names are variable and there are 100+ columns

I obviously want to avoid changing all the OFFs to ONs (I'm happy to change the first or last, just not more than one.)
(the UPDATE is through PHP and my current solution is to do a SELECT and create an array of the OFF values then change in PHP before UDATING - but this requries extra MYSQL queries... )

Comment: Not sure at all what you want to do... change only Wednesday to off, but leave friday/xmas alone? Seems like this table design is in some major need of normalization.

Comment: basically yes, change one of the OFFS and leave the others

Comment: very difficult with a regular query. You'd be far better off normalizing the table design to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `LIMIT` clause.

`UPDATE table SET column='value' WHERE condition='value' LIMIT 1`

Comment: but won't that change all values that = OFF to =ON?

Comment: and the column is variable, the problem is that I don't know which one it is that i want to update

Answer (score 0):

Usual way is simply to build up the query string
PSEUDO CODE !

```
qry = "Update Table Set " + NameValuesDelimited + " Where ...."
```

NameValues is just a list of "Column1 = 0" "Column2 = 2", and delimited puts commas in to give you a statement sql will understand e.g.

```
Update Table Set C1 = 0, c2 = 6, c9 = 8 Where KeyName = 44
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking into the pseudo code idea and given the volume of columns, and my lack of expertise, I thought it something I can look at later - the array solution will have to stand for the tiime being